# CasperJS with MongoDB NPM Module

Tags: node.js, mongodb, phantomjs, casperjs

I'm running CasperJS 1.1.0-DEV and require the `mongoskin` NPM module to insert documents into Mongodb.

However using the `mongoskin` NPM module

```
var mongo = require('mongoskin')
var db = mongo.db('mongodb://localhost:27017/test', {native_parser: true})')
```

throws the error

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: process

  /Users/username/casper-test/node_modules/mongoskin/index.js:1
  /Users/username/casper-test/node_modules/mongoskin/index.js:2
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'mongo.db('mongodb://localhost:27017/test', {native_parser: true})')

  test.js:3
```

How should be the correct way to use CasperJS together with an NPM module like `mongoskin`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CasperJS is built on top of PhantomJS which itself has a different execution environment from node.js. CasperJS can use a similar module infrastructure as node.js, but most node modules cannot be run directly in CasperJS. Since PhantomJS doesn't provide the same base modules, you can't use modules that use them. It probably won't be possible to rewrite mongoskin for it to use the PhantomJS modules.

The other way would be to write a node.js script that uses mongoskin and then call node with that script through the [`child_process` module](http://phantomjs.org/api/child_process/). You will need to synchronize that with the control flow in CasperJS, so you can use `casper.waitFor()` for that:

```
var execFile = require("child_process").execFile;

casper.callMongoskin = function(then, onTimeout, timeout){
    var finished = false;
    var results;
    execFile("node", ["mongoskin_script.js"], null, function (err, stdout, stderr) {
        console.log("execFileSTDOUT:", JSON.stringify(stdout));
        console.log("execFileSTDERR:", JSON.stringify(stderr));
        results = {stuff: "..."};
        finished = true;
    });
    this.waitFor(function(){
        return finished;
    }, function _then(){
        if (typeof then === "function") {
            then.call(this, results);
        }
    }, onTimeout, timeout);
};
casper.thenCallMongoskin = function(then, onTimeout, timeout){
    return this.then(function(){
        this.callMongoskin(then, onTimeout, timeout);
    });
};
```

I'll let you figure out what you want to pass in. Here's how you'd use it:

```
casper.start(url).thenCallMongoskin(function(results){
    require('utils').dump(results);
}).run();
```

Comment: I replaced `result` with `results` in `then.call(this, result);` because the variable `result` is not defined anyway, but now I'm getting an error `TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'then.call(this, results)')`. I'm using the function via `casper.thenCallMongoskin`

Comment: The first one was a typo. I don't know what you mean for the second one. If you pass in a `then` callback, it can't be undefined. If I try my code, `stuff` is dumped to the console. I've added an if-branch to check if `then` is a function.